# I cannt get the index in the program as i try many times

Tags: java

i want to get the index in the student to return 
but it cannt compare . i donnt know what is the mintake here 
would soome one figure it out

```
public int search(String[][] student, String searchKey) {
    int search = 0;
    int column = student.length;
    int row = student[1].length;
    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%s", student[i][j]);
            if ((student[i][j]).equals(searchKey))
                search = i;

        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: you have a two dimensional loop so you can find element with one index.

Comment: You need to `return search` if/when you've found the match.

Comment: Why a 2d String array to store a String.?

Comment: i need the column of the  found key .

Answer (score 0):

```
class FindKey

{
    public int search(String[][] student, String searchKey) {
    int search = 0;
    int column = student.length;
    int row = student[1].length;
    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            if ((student[i][j]).equals(searchKey)){
               System.out.println(j);
               return j;
            }


        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FindKey search = new FindKey();
    String[][] book ={{"1", "2"} , {"2", "4"}} ;
    search.search(book, "2");

}
}
```

try this

Comment: what if the array has duplicate keys..which column it should return?